# HtpsURLConnection cannot establish connection

Tags: android, rest, ssl

I need to connect to server using `SSL` with `REST`. I am using `HttpsURLConnection` but somehow I cannot even get response code from server. The url is correct and when I try to get response code, it just throws nullPointerException.

Code snippet:

```
URL url = new URL("https", "xxx.com/yyy/zzz.svc", "myApi/test");


HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Log.e("Response code", "Response from server: " + conn.getResponseCode());
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Note: I have to add remote server address and authorization token to header, but it have to return some response code anyway. For authorization error I have to receive error 400.

EDIT: The nullPointerException was hidden under `Malformed URL`.

Comment: Is your server response in JSON ?

Comment: yes, it is. But why does it matter?

Comment: Yes it matters. Because you need to parse the data accordingly as per its response format.

Comment: So, what should I do to get the response that is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How to parse / read JSON data from the URL.](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-how-parse)

Comment: I know how to parse JSON, but I should get something from server anyway, even if it is error message.

Comment: Have you checked your webservice in Rest Client ? Do you get the response in REST Client? Please show your response .

Comment: Everything is fine, just malformed url.